# EXTJS Proxy type rest mal-formatted url for DELETE http request

Tags: rest, extjs

I'm having trouble when I try to do a delete object by using restful:
In an xtype "actioncolumn" button I have this handler:

```
handler: function (grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                            Ext.MessageBox.confirm('Delete', 'Are you sure ?', function (btn) {
                                if (btn === 'yes') {
                                    var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
                                    store.removeAt(rowIndex);
                                    store.sync();
                                }
                            });
}
```

And when I click on delete button following url is requested:

`http://10.100.0.194:8080/api/users/App.model.User-6`

Where the hell comes from: App.model.User-6 ?, it should be user id object (int). On my model I've idProperty: user_id already.

Thanks for helping

Comment: show your model\store code

Comment: I already fixed it, it was because my User's Models had "user_id" as "id", so I changed to "id" instead of "user_id"... and now it's working ;)